# SwiftUI Map: How to convert screen coordinates to map coordinates?

Tags: swiftui, draggable, coordinate-transformation, mapview

**Setup:**

I am converting an app to SwiftUI. This app had an `MKMapView` with annotations that could be dragged on the map.
I was able to write a first version of the SwiftUI app with a draggable image.
It uses a `View` that is displayed as annotation on the map:

```
struct AnnotationView: View {
    var buyLocationNameBeforeDragging: String
    @State private var isDragging = false
    @GestureState var dragAmount = CGSize.zero
    var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    
    func coordinateFrom(region: MKCoordinateRegion, dragAmount: CGSize) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D() // How to compute this?
        return coordinate
    }
    
    var drag: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { _ in
                self.isDragging = true
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                self.isDragging = false
                let coreDataManager = testOrPreview ? CoreDataManager.test : CoreDataManager.shared
                let newCoordinate = coordinateFrom(region: region, dragAmount: dragAmount)
                // Move the dragged place to the new coordinate
                // …
            }
            .updating($dragAmount) { value, state, transaction in
                state = value.translation
            }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Image("PinRed")
            .offset(dragAmount)
            .defersSystemGestures(on: .all)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("tapped")
            }
            .gesture(drag)
    }
}
```

It is possible to tap the annotation pin, and - after tapping longer - to drag the pin to a new location.

**Problem:**

To update my model, I need the endpoint coordinates of the drag on the map. These should be computed in `func coordinateFrom` (see above), but I have no idea how to do this.
`MKMapView` has e.g. a function `convert(_:toCoordinateFrom:)`, but SwiftUI's `Map` has nothing like this.

**Question:**

How to do the conversion?

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved.
I 1st converted `var drag: some Gesture` to a function:

```
func drag(geo: GeometryProxy) -> some Gesture {
    DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .named("screen"))
        .onChanged { value in
            self.isDragging = true
        }
        .onEnded { _ in
            self.isDragging = false
            let coreDataManager = testOrPreview ? CoreDataManager.test : CoreDataManager.shared
            let newCoordinate = coordinateFrom(region: region, geo: geo, dragAmount: dragAmount)
            // Move the dragged place to the new coordinate
            // …
        }
        .updating($dragAmount) { value, state, transaction in
            state = value.translation
        }
}
```

where `geo` is supplied by the body of the `AnnotationView`, and `.coordinateSpace(name: "screen")` has been applied to the view displaying the map:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        Image("PinRed")
            .offset(dragAmount)
            .defersSystemGestures(on: .all)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Global center: \(geo.frame(in: .global).midX) x \(geo.frame(in: .global).midY)")
            }
            .gesture(drag(geo: geo))
    }
    .frame(width: 40, height: 30)
}
```

Next, I converted the map coordinates from screen coordinates to map coordinates using the old `MKMapView` as:

```
func coordinateFrom(region: MKCoordinateRegion, geo: GeometryProxy, dragAmount: CGSize) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    let mkMapView = MKMapView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))
    mkMapView.region = region
    let frame = geo.frame(in: .global)
    let dragEndPoint = CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x + dragAmount.width, y: frame.origin.y + dragAmount.height)
    let dragEndCFoordinate = mkMapView.convert(dragEndPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mkMapView)
    return dragEndCFoordinate
}
```

Here, I assume the `MKMapView` and SwiftUI `Map` use the same coordinate transforms. In my case, I don't see any differences.

Comment: When I use that code, the translation from Geometry Reader to Map Coords is wrong (drags wrong direction, the length is much higher) . Does that work for you perfectly?

Comment: Hmmm... For me, it does work correctly. I just check that it does.

Comment: I checked it and it still works.